# HADOOP - number of output files produced as mapper output

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

i want to know how many files will be produced if only a single mapper ( no reducer,no combiner etc ) is run
for all file splits .

example-
if there are 4 file splits . then there is single mapper that will process all file splits.
how many files as mapper output ?? -> one or four

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each map task will produce one output file.  If you have one file on HDFS that is split into four blocks, you will get four output files from a Map-Only job.  If the input file is not in a splittable format, like GZip, it will be combined and only one mapper will act on it, outputting one file.

Comment: Thank you so much.